# Add non existing item to list

Tags: linq, lambda

I am trying to fill a list with objects which haven't been added yet by random to a list. So I loop rInt times through a list and want to pick randomly objects and add them to the list if they does not already exist:

```
collectionList = new List<CollectionSccmCM>();

                        Random r = new Random();
                        int rInt = r.Next(0, 5);
                        for(int i=0; i<=rInt; i++){
                            collectionList.Add(_context.CollectionApplications.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Where(x => collectionList.Any(y => y.CollectionID !=(x.collection_id.ToString()))).Select(x => new CollectionSccmCM(){CollectionID= x.collection_id.ToString(), Name=x.collection_name}).FirstOrDefault());
                    }
```

I seems that I have a mistake in the orderby and where part, but I cannot figure out the error. When I put a toList between I dont receive any syntax error anymore, but also doesn't work.

Any tip what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Edit:

I did a mistake and had to use contains, but still not working:

```
collectionList.Add(_context.CollectionApplications.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Where(x => collectionList.Any(y => !y.CollectionID.Contains(x.collection_id.ToString()))).Select(x => new CollectionSccmCM(){CollectionID= x.collection_id.ToString(), Name=x.collection_name}).FirstOrDefault());
```

Edit:
Got it working with a select, but not so happy with it and dont understand why the otherone wasnt working.

```
collectionList.Add(_context.CollectionApplications.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Where(x => !collectionList.Select(y => y.CollectionID).ToList().Contains(x.collection_id.ToString())).Select(x => new CollectionSccmCM(){CollectionID= x.collection_id.ToString(), Name=x.collection_name}).FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest you consider adding some whitespace to your LINQ. I would break your first example down as follows:

```cs
collectionList.Add(
    _context.CollectionApplications
        .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
        .Where(x => collectionList.Any(y => y.CollectionID !=(x.collection_id.ToString())))
        .Select(x => new CollectionSccmCM() {
            CollectionID = x.collection_id.ToString(), 
            Name = x.collection_name
        }).FirstOrDefault()
);
```

Looking at your `Where` call, you are including in the possible elements to add, those elements where any of the collection IDs doesn't match (`collectionList.Any(y => ... )`). That's all of them (unless you only have one element in `collectionList`).

You probably want to use `All` instead of `Any` -- where **all** of the collection IDs don't match:

```cs
        .Where(x => collectionList.All(y => y.CollectionID != x.collection_id.ToString()))
```